# iTunes RSS JSON Feed

Tags: jquery, json

I have been trying to design a simple iTunes JSON feed to output the 'top albums' on my webpage, moreover, I cannot seem to produce/output any results. The iTunes JSON feed I use is from https://rss.itunes.apple.com/en-us, my code is below. I have been using 'artistName' to try to output anything I could..

https://jsfiddle.net/jmce67yb/20/

```
$.getJSON('https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/us/apple-music/top-albums/all/100/explicit.json,' function(data) {
    $('#output').append('<li>' + data[i].artistName);
    }
});
```

Comment: If I try out your fiddler link I get this error in the javascript console `Failed to load https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/us/apple-music/top-albums/all/100/explicit.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`Try googling that for a start

Comment: Also the items are not in the "top" level of the `data` object. The array of items is in `data.feed.results`

Comment: What mortdb said...you won't be able to do this in JavaScript due to CORS restrictions - check your browser's console for the relevant error message. You'll have to use a server-side script, and then write the results into your HTML using that.

Comment: Would Node.js be a better option to use for this?

Comment: It's just one of many. If you want to stick to using JavaScript, but just using it server-side, then Node is the tool for that. But you can use anything - PHP, Python, Java, C# etc - whatever your server will run and you're comfortable coding in.